# The camera lens on iPod touch 5th gen

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, camera

My iPhone 6 camera protrudes slightly and so does my iPod touch 5th gen, but I don't worry about scratching my iPhone camera because I know it's coated in sapphire. Is the iPod touch protruding camera also sapphire? Or is it just the same glass as the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPod touch 5 is older then the iPhone 6 (released with the iPhone 5) so no, it does not have a sapphire coating. However, it generally is durable enough for most things before it scratches.

Comment: Isn't iPhone 5 camera also made of sapphire lens?

Comment: @Moist No. The sapphire lens were new, beginning with the iPhone 6.